# Fiware Wirecloud Mahup: ngsi-source operator can't reach NGSI Proxy

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to use Wirecloud the latest version available for a simple mashup project. I'm using the [ngsi-source operator](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-source-operator) to retrieve data from Orion, but this is not possible because I often encounter an **NGSI Proxy Connection Error (504 Gateway Timeout)**.

I tried with different installations of the [NGSI Proxy](https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsi-proxy) in different servers and I have noticed that I have a 200 status in the inner REST calls made by the ngsi-source operator, only when the NGSI Proxy is **reachable from the Wirecloud server installation** (django server).

When the proxy is reachable only from my browser (local machine), I encounter the 504 status.

The NGSI Proxy has to be reachable from the Wirecloud installation?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I've noticed that the first rest call made by the ngsi-source operator is composed in this way **http://<wirecloud domain>/cdp/http/<ngsi-proxy domain>/eventsource**. This may cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the NGSI proxy has to be reachable from the WireCloud instance. The url you were seeing (`http://<wirecloud domain>/cdp/http/<ngsi-proxy domain>/eventsource`) is caused by the use of the Cross Domain Proxy. We developed the NGSI proxy service to allow cross domain requests from browsers and the event source endpoint cannot be used without a direct connection from the client side, so I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/281) in the github repo to solve this bug.

Comment: The most difficult thing to understand for me, is that every request made from browser uses a **proxy in Django Back End** . In the latest version 1.0.1, I don't face the problem.